# How can I keep its face from breaking?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I made a fluffy toy and set armature using automatic weight. Then changed to pose mode and I moved head bone, its face was broke as image.
So how can I fix it? I already tried to fix it by setting of weight paint but it doesn't work.I tried to join the objects too, but this way broke the setting of hair particle.

Thank you for reading.
[image]
[image]

blender version:2.83
OS: Windows 10

Comment: Can you please explain how it broke, does it got separated or overlapping, adding the image it seems to be attached and only rotated a bit weirdly

Comment: After I read your comment, I reviewed setting of weight paint and tried to fix it...And surprisingly I could fix this by myself! Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Hi. Please add an answer showing how you fixed the problem so other people can benefit. Thanks.

Comment: This problem's cause was automatic weight. There was unnecessary weight on eyes and nose, so they were influenced by rotate of shoulder and arm. I could solve this by reviewing setting of weight paint and delete unnecessary weight. I know this is very elementary problem and embarrassed but I wish this question could help someone who has similar problem. Thank you.